# For loop index type deduction best practice

Tags: c++, c++11, type-deduction

Let's say, I have a container `c` of a type that provides a `size()` method and I want to loop over this container while keeping track of each item's index:

```
for (/*TODO*/ i = 0; i < c.size(); i++) {...}
```

In a post-C++11 world, where automatic type deduction solves so many problems nicely. What should we use in place of the `TODO` above? The only thing that seems correct to me, no matter what the type of `size()` is, is the following:

```
for (decltype(c.size()) i = 0; i < c.size(); i++) {...}
```

But this seems overly verbose and ,in my opinion, doesn't help readability.

Another solution might be this:

```
for (auto end = c.size(), i = 0; i < end; i++) {...}
```

But this doesn't help readability either and, of course, doesn't have the same semantics as the original snippet.

So, my question is: what is the best way to deduce the type of a loop index variable, given only the type of the index' limit.

Comment: Well, you may use `foreach` loop and don't bother with counters at all :) Also all standard container types _usually_ define `size_type`

Comment: @user3159253: Well, in my case I *do* care about the item's index :-) I might also be dealing with non-standard containers.

Comment: Is the aim to write generic (i.e templated code) that works regardless of the type of `c` or are you just looking for one best-practice that works in all circumstances?

Comment: Use iterators, and std algorithms and lambdas, and you don't have to worry about it as much.

Comment: @ChrisDrew: It's more of a best-practice question.

Comment: @NeilKirk: Could you elaborate? I don't see how that would help given that I need the index.

Comment: @Job (it - begin_it) can give you the index for a random-access iterator. Otherwise I just use size_t for a general index.

Comment: @NeilKirk: Well, I sometimes have to work with containers that don't have iterators. Also, `size_t`, while probably a good guess, is not guaranteed to be a safe replacement for `decltype(c.size())`.

Comment: @Job: I address that concern about `size_t` in my revised answer.

Comment: The last form does not compile due to inconsistent type deduction (`size_type` for `end` vs `int` for `i`). Live demo [here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/39I0KEX9F7Qq7K1d).

Answer (score 4):

Short answer to the *first* question in your text: You should replace the `/*TODO*/` by `unsigned`, `std::size_t` or something similar, meaning: **don't bother deducing the type**, just pick a type suitable for any reasonable container size.

This would be an unsigned, reasonably large type so the compiler is not tempted to yell at you beacuse of possible precision losses. In the comments above you write that `size_t` is not *guaranteed* to be a good replacement to `decltype(c.size())`, but while it is not impossible to implement a container that has an index incompatible to `size_t`, such indizes would most surely not be numbers (and thus incompatible to `i = 0`), and the containers would not have a `size` method either. A `size()` method implies a nonnegative integral, and since `size_t` is designed for exact those numbers, it will be close to impossible to have a container of a size that cannot be represented by it.

Your *second* question aims at how to deduce the type, and you already have provided the easiest, yet imperfect answers. If you want a solution that is not as verbose as `decltype` and not as surprising to read as `auto end`, you could define a template alias and a generator function for the starting index in some utility header:

```
template <class T> 
using index_t = decltype(std::declval<T>().size());

template <class T, class U>
constexpr index_t<T> index(T&&, U u) { return u; }

//and then in the actual location of the loop:
for (auto i = index(c,0); i < c.size(); ++i) {...}
//which is the same as
for (auto i = index_t<std::vector<int>>(0); i < c.size(); ++i) {...}
```

If you want to have a more general index-type, e.g. for arrays and classes that don't have a `size` method, it gets a bit more complicated, because template aliases may not be specialized:

```
template <class T>
struct index_type {
  using type = decltype(std::declval<T>().size());
};

template <class T>
using index_t = typename index_type<T>::type;

template <class T, class U>
constexpr index_t<T> index(T&&, U u) { return u; }

//index_type specializations
template <class U, std::size_t N>
struct index_type<U[N]> { 
  using type = decltype(N); 
};

template <>
struct index_type<System::AnsiString::AnsiString> { //YUCK! VCL!
  using type = int; 
};
```

However, this is a lot of stuff just for the few cases where you actually need an index and a simple foreach loop is not sufficient.

Comment: Although I would probably never use this technique, it is the only answer that somewhat does what I asked for. I'll accept it in a couple of days if nothing else comes up.

Comment: I agree that it is a somewhat cumbersome answer, and I would probably never use it either. I have edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: I agree that with any *reasonable* container, `size_t` should do the trick. However, It's certainly not *impossible* to create a container with a `size()` incompatible with `size_t`. One example are Qt's containers where `size()` returns an `int`. Also, since `size_t` is only guaranteed to be large enough to address every byte in the address space, a container that tries to address every *bit* in the address space could have a `size()` incompatible with `size_t`.

Comment: While QT's containers (and VCLs `AnsiString::Length`) return `int` they are still nonnegative AFAIK, so `size_t` should be okay. wrt bit-addressing containers: If you switch between containers where the semantics of indexing is so very different, then the whole loop semantics would change and manually changing the index type would be the least of your problems in that loop. Anyways, in one of the comments you said it was a "best practice" question, and nifty corner cases usually are not covered by best practices ;-)

Comment: Although they do indeed return non-negative `int`s, using `size_t` as index variable will produce compiler warnings about comparing integers with different signs. This is what I meant with "incompatible with `size_t`". About the bit-addressing containers, I don't see how the indexing semantics of `vector<bool>` are so very different from other containers. Anyway, you are completely right about the "best practice" remark :-)

Comment: A container which transparently loads a file's contents into memory as needed could legitimately have `size()` as an integral type with a value greater than `SIZE_MAX`.

Answer (score 2):

If c is a container you can use `container::size_type`.

Comment: *Only* if it is a "standard" container type which, unfortunately, isn't always the case.

Comment: If `c` is not a "standard" container I would be wary of writing generic code and use the actual type.

Comment: @ChrisDrew: Well I don't really agree. I want to be independent of the actual type because it might change in the future.

Comment: @Job What do you want to do with the index? Because if you don't know if it is unsigned or signed (e.g [QT vector](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qvector.html) you need to be very careful what you do with it (especially comparisons).

Comment: @ChrisDrew: Most often you'll use it to access the items of the container, e.g., `c.getItem(i)`, for containers without decent iterators. But I've had many other use cases.

Comment: -1 because I asked explicitly about *deducing* the type.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the precedence that I follow

> 1) `range-for`
>   2) `iterator/begin()/end()` with type deduced with `auto`.

For cases where indexing is required, which is the subject here, I prefer to use

```
for( auto i = 0u; i < c.size(); ++i) {...}
```

Even if I misses to add `u` in `0`, compiler will warn me anyway.

---

Would have loved `decltype` if it is not too verbose

```
for (decltype(c.size()) i = 0; i < c.size(); i++) {...}
```

Answer (score 0):

As a matter of fact, I have seen plenty of times (*cough* llvm, clang) where they do use

```
for (/* type */ iter = begin(), End = end(); iter != End; ++i);
```

The advantage of having `End` evaluated at the beginning is that the compiler can be sure that it doesn't need to call it every time. For collections that where calculating the end is trivial and the compiler is already able to deduce that it doesn't need to call end() multiple times it won't help, but in other cases it will.

Or you could always use a helper:

[Implementing enumerate_foreach based on Boost foreach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11733364/implementing-enumerate-foreach-based-on-boost-foreach)

Comment: Yes, I know this is often used and I also know the advantages. The problem is that in my case, it only works if `end` comes before `iter`: `for (auto end = ..., i = 0; ...)`. I think this is a little confusing.

Comment: compiler will not re-evaluate `end()` if it can see that container is not modified.

Comment: @Abyx not exactly. It will not reevaluate `end()` if it can see that the outcome will not change. Consider a container whose implementation of the end() method is in a separate source file. For all the compiler knows, `end()` could return a random value everytime it is called, so it *has* to reevaluate it.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm... this needs C++14 or a compiler that supports auto in the lambda parameters. If you're using this pattern a lot, then a helping function might be useful:

```
template< typename Container, typename Callable >
void for_each_index( Container& container, Callable callable )
{
    for (decltype(container.size()) i = 0; i < container.size(); i++)
    {
        callable(i);
    }
}
```

Use as:

```
for_each_index(c, [] (auto index) {
    // ...
});
```